# Several interaction terms in regression model

Tags: regression, interaction

Please excuse if this question has already been asked. Is it possible to include several interaction terms into one model (I am keeping the main effects in). So I have:

M1: X1, X2, X3

M2: X1, X2, X3, X1 x X2

M3: X1, X2, X3, X1 x X3

M4: X1, X2, X3, X1 x X3, X1 x X2 (this one gives me results very hard to interpret - due to strange sign changes)

I would like to go with only M1-M3 but I am worried that reviewers will ask why I did not do M4.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do it. I could indeed see that a reviewer might ask that question. Is it perhaps easier to interpret the predictions for particular covariate combinations?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am mainly struggeling with the interpretation that in M2 and M3 the interaction terms are both negative and when I put them together in the model one of them is either not significant or there is a positive significant interaction term (M4). I am just wondering if there is an additional value in including them both. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

First, it is possible to have multiple interaction terms in a model.

Second, people may ask why you included some interaction terms and not others - you  need to have a good answer.

Third, "things were hard to interpret" is not a good answer.

So, how to look at model M4?  In addition to trying to interpret the parameters, you should look at the predictions the model makes.  Look at the predicted Y for various combinations of X1, X2 and X3.  Make graphs. What graphs you should make depends on the nature of the X variables but if all are continuous then coplots can be good.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I am working with social network data, therefore plotting parameters is difficult. I know which parameters I would like to include, the main question I had (and was answered) was if it will give me meaningful results in general. Thanks again